# writing the author's name at the end of the title in css

Tags: css

My HTML code:-

```
<div class='store_detail-level1'>
    <span class='book_name'>How To Avoid Climate Disaster</span>
    <br>
    <span class='author_name'>Bill Gates</span>
</div>
```

I want like this

```
 How To Avoid Climate Disaster
                             by Bill Gates
```

Key Points:-

1. content of class 'book_name' is dynamic, which means it's from the database
2. It must be responsive

Responsive means for mobile screen itr may be like:-

```
How To Avoid Climate
Disaster
       by Bill Gates
```

Comment: _"It must be responsive"_ - meaning what, _exactly?_ How do you want this to behave, if the width was so small, that f.e. only the "by" would still fit on the same line?

Comment: And what if the book name itself was so long, that it breaks into two (or maybe even more) lines? Say `How To Avoid Climate` was on line 1, and `Disaster` on the next - where do you want to align the author name then?

Comment: now i edited it look again

Comment: Making the name element inline-block and adding a top margin halfway works, https://jsfiddle.net/1je2c8qy/ - until the available width is so that the name does not fit next to the book title any more (play with the width set for body in inspector, to see how it behaves at different widths), then that margin will cause an additional empty line between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var divwidth = document.getElementById('getthisid').clientWidth;
document.getElementById("setthisid").style.marginLeft = divwidth+'px';
```

```css
.store_detail-level1{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id='getthisid' class='store_detail-level1'>
  <div class='book_name_container'>
    <span class='book_name'>How To Avoid Climate Disaster</span>
  </div>
    
  <div id='setthisid' class='author_name_container'>
    <span class='author_name'>by Bill Gates</span>
  </div>
</div>
```